# Is there an analoge to rake tasks in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I've used `rake` tasks in my ruby on rails work in the past, and I'm wondering if the node.js framework express has anything similar. Basically, something that loads the environment and lets you execute scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [Jake](http://howtonode.org/intro-to-jake)?

> Jake is a JavaScript build program for Node.js, with capabilities similar to GNU Make or Ruby's Rake. If you've ever built projects with Rake, you'll be very at home using Jake